# Batch update with in clause

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

Is it possible to execute a batch update with a variable length in-clause against an sqlite db?

```
val data = Seq(
  Seq(Set(1,2,3), 50),
  Seq(Set(4,5,6,7), 51)
)

NamedDB(symbol).localTx { implicit s: DBSession =>
  sql"""
    update table_a
    set xs=(
      select group_concat(x) from (
        select distinct x from table_b where id in (?)
      )
    ) where id=?
  """.batch(xs.map(_.data): _*).apply()
}
```

This default approach causes scalikejdbc to log that the parameter is being set as an object (a warning?) and the result is that no updates are applied.

I tried using a parameter binder, but it is not possible to set the `in (?)` parameter as an array type as sqlite (and its JDBC driver) do not support arrays.

The alternative is to alter the SQL text to have a `?` per value in the clause. This is not possible with a batch update as different rows have different quantities of values.

Answer (score 0):

My work-around is to group data by qty of in clause params and execute a separate batch update for each.

```
xs.map(_.data).groupBy(_.size - 1).foreach { case (length, data) =>
  NamedDB(symbol).localTx { implicit s: DBSession =>
    val inClauseParams = ("?" * length).mkString(",")
    SQL(
      s"""
       update table_a set xs=(
         select group_concat(x) from (
           select distinct x from table_b where id in ($inClauseParams)
         )
       ) where id=?
     """
    ).batch(data: _*).apply()
  }
}
```